# How to access a variable using just variable name and set a value for the same variable using function call syntax?

Tags: javascript

Is there a mechanism in javascript to define `counter` variable or any other variable so that when I want to access the value of this variable I should use variable name: `var result = counter + 1` and when I want to set a value for this same variable I should use: `counter(counter + 2)`
function call syntax with same name. These two conditions should be kept. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi. I thought about proxies, getters and setters and since I am less experienced in programming I could not find a solution for this problem myself.

Comment: I did not understand anything!

Comment: You are aware that `javascript` is a client side language. If you want to store `result` or use `counter` as a variable it will only be used on that clients browser... for this to be stored for your own use other than that single client you will need some server-side communication. With client-side languages you can refresh the page and all memory/changes are gone unless you use cookie/local storage but even then it will only be saved on that clients computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that could just make the code harder to read. anyway, you can replace the valueOf method of the function to return a number.

The counter function will only be evaluated to a number when you try to use it as a number.

```js
function counter(value) {
  counter.value = value;
}

counter.valueOf = function() { return this.value || 0; }

// it only works when used as a number
var result = counter + 1
counter(counter + 2)
var result2 = counter + 1
// simple assignment will result in a function
var result3 = counter

console.log(result)
console.log(result2)
console.log(result3)
```

Comment: I hoped there was a way to use multiple types as the value. At least I could not find. And I appreciate your answer. Thank you.